# access of content of loaded swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-builder, action

I want to access content of a loaded `SWF` file. I used following code,

```
function _browse(e:MouseEvent):void
{  
     loader.load(new URLRequest("artwork3.swf.swf"));
     loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,loading);
     target_clip.addChild(loader);
}

function loading(event:Event)
{
     trace(target_clip.getChildAt(0));
     trace(target_clip.getChildAt(1));
}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, handleComplete );
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("artwork3.swf.swf");
loader.load(request);

protected function handleComplete(event:Event):void
{   
    DisplayObject loadedSwf = target_clip.addChild(event.currentTarget.content as DisplayObject) as DisplayObject;
    //you can access variables from loaded swf
    trace(loadedSwf.name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function _browse(e:MouseEvent):void
    {  
         loader.load(new URLRequest("artwork3.swf.swf"));
         loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,loading);
         target_clip.addChild(loader);
    }
    function loading(event:Event)
    {
         var myLoadedSwf:MovieClip = loader.content as MovieClip;

         trace(myLoadedSwf.getChildAt(0));
         trace(myLoadedSwf.getChildAt(1));
         //trace(target_clip.getChildAt(0));
         //trace(target_clip.getChildAt(1));
    }
```

Comment: showing error,TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

Comment: Sorry, typo, should be myLoadedSwf instead of myLoadedSwf_clip. I corrected code

Answer (score 0):

Try `MovieClip(loader.content)` instead of target_clip like so,

```
function _browse(e:MouseEvent):void
{  
     loader.load(new URLRequest("artwork3.swf.swf"));
     loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,loading);
     target_clip.addChild(loader);
}

function loading(event:Event)
{
     trace(MovieClip(loader.content).getChildAt(0));
     trace(MovieClip(loader.content).getChildAt(1));
}
```

Best luck.